# Kotlin compile error with OkHttp when adding a method using Request

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am using OkHhttp and Retrofit in a project. I have a 'RestClient' java class which is building OkHttp and retrofit clients, and I have a kotlin compile error when I add a method in the class with `Request`

The following code is compiling without problem :

```
private OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
            int flags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE;
            String header = calculateHeader()
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", header).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });
    return builder.build();
}
```

But if I add a method to calculate the header based on the `Request` it fails

```
private OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> {
            int flags = Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE;
            String header = calculateHeader(chain.request())
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", header).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        });
    return builder.build();
}

private String calculateHeader(Request request) {/** ... */ }
```

Then I have the following error with Kotlin compiler :

`error: cannot access Request class file for okhttp3.Request not found. Consult the following stack trace for details`

Unfortunately there is no stack trace.
I tried to disable Proguard and R8 but without success, the same error remains and the only way to make this message disappear is to remove the `Request` param from the method.

What I am missing there?

Comment: Did you try to compile from command line? Like `./gradlew clean assembleDebug`. To exclude possible AndroidStudio issues.

Comment: Yes I tried to clean everything, and to rollback to the previous commit and go step by step to identify the problem and the same issue happened.